# Converting Unicode characters to the "\uxxxx" form

Tags: php, unicode

I'm trying to convert characters, like À, to their escaped form, such as `\u00c0`.  I know this can be done with `json_encode`, but the function adds backslashes to special characters. (I'm not actually hoping to get a json object, just string conversion):

`$str = 'À ß \ Ć " Ď < Ĕ';`

For the string above, it'll return

`$str = '\u00c0 \u00df \\ \u0106 \" \u010e < \u0114';`

and if I `stripslashes`, it will also strip the one before each `uxxxx`.

Is there a function for this particular conversion? Or what is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want those backslashes the way they are?  They must be there if you don't want arbitrary broken strings, JSON or not.

Comment: OK, forget about json_encode. My question can be simplified to `how can I convert a character to \uxxxx unicode?`

Comment: @brad that is **unicode to utf-8**. I'm asking for **utf-8 to unicode** conversion.

Comment: Which is it?  Make up your mind.  You specifically say in your latest comment that you want to convert `\uxxxx` strings to unicode.

Comment: @Brad funny. yes I do want the result to be `unicode` like \uxxxx. but look at the information you provided, it's `unicode` to `utf-8`. If you can't provide a solution, just do what you need to do or just sit back and watch, don't ask `"why do/don't you want it this/that way?"` everyone has his/her own purpose, they don't have to be thinking what you are thinking!

Comment: Brad, why did @cryptic understand my question and provided a working solution while you completely understood it the wrong way?

Comment: I apologize, I am unable to understand what you are wanting to do.  I am happy that someone else was able to understand and provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'À ß \ Ć " Ď < Ĕ';

echo trim(preg_replace('/\\\\([^u])/', "$1", json_encode($str)), '"');
// ouptuts: \u00c0 \u00df \ \u0106 " \u010e < \u0114
```

I know it uses json_encode(), but it's the easiest way to convert to \uXXXX

Comment: sorry to be picky, but it fails on `À ß \ Ć " Ď \\uicode < Ĕ` where it strips the first backslash from `\\unicode`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code for going back and forward

### **Code** :

```
if (!function_exists('codepoint_encode')) {
    function codepoint_encode($str) {
        return substr(json_encode($str), 1, -1);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('codepoint_decode')) {
    function codepoint_decode($str) {
        return json_decode(sprintf('"%s"', $str));
    }
}
```

### **How to use** :

```
echo "\nUse JSON encoding / decoding\n";
var_dump(codepoint_encode("我好"));
var_dump(codepoint_decode('\u6211\u597d'));
```

### **Output** :

```
Use JSON encoding / decoding
string(12) "\u6211\u597d"
string(6) "我好"
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to @cryptic's answer:

**script**

```
$str = 'À ß \ Ć " Ď < Ĕ \\\\uxxx';
echo trim(preg_replace('/\\\\([^u])/', "$1", json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)), '"');
```

**output**

```
\u00c0 \u00df \ \u0106 " \u010e < \u0114 \\uxxx
```

Comment: well, the output should be `\u00c0 \u00df \ \u0106 " \u010e < \u0114`

Comment: Well my encoding generated the hex values you see, but you have the '\' and '"' escaped in the OP, so I've added addslashes() to escape those before doing the replace.

Comment: Can you tell me what encoding you are using in your php test file?  Mine is UTF-8 and what comes out is the output I have posted.

Comment: If you don't want the quote and slash escaped, just remove the call to addslashes() in my example - that's actually how it was originally - Perhaps I misread your question in thinking you wanted them escaped.

Comment: but your output is definitely not what I wanted. my file is encoded with utf-8. and I want the result to be like `json_encode($str)`, BUT `without slashes added`. `\u00c0 \u00df \ \u0106 " \u010e < \u0114`

Comment: @cryptic is close, but it fails on string like `\\uxxx`

Comment: I've updated mine as a modified version of @crytpic's - Assuming you use `\\\\uxxx` in your PHP string, which decodes to `\\uxxx` for processing, this version appears to work as desired.

Comment: ok, it was my bad. cryptic was right about his code. I was testing a string right from php file, so of course it parses \\ to \. I actually need to read string from a file, and his code does it right.

Comment: and also, I'm using 5.2 here. option parameter was added in 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertChars($str) {
    return json_decode("\"$str\"");
}
```

Comment: It's very helpful to actually explain your code and why this solves the problem, rather than just dumping the code lines.